# Wilcox test on values in a single data frame column, based on condition from another column

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to undertake the Wilcox test on a single column, which is conditioned on another column. I keep on getting an error, such as below:

> Error in wilcox.test.default(mtcars %>% filter(am == 1) %>%
> select(mpg),  :    'x' must be numeric

I have produced an example below using the mtcars dataset, and was wondering if someone could advise me on what I'm doing wrong

```
wilcox.test(mtcars%>%filter(am==1)%>%select(mpg),
            mtcars%>%filter(am==0)%>%select(mpg))
```

Is it linked to the variables being input into the test are of different lengths?

Comment: Try the formula form: `wilcox.test(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$am)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with @Dave2e that using the formula interface would be much cleaner, if you want to use `dplyr` you're going to have to `pull` `mpg` not `select` it.

```r
library(dplyr)


wilcox.test(mtcars %>% filter(am==1) %>% pull(mpg),
            mtcars %>% filter(am==0) %>% pull(mpg))
#> Warning in wilcox.test.default(mtcars %>% filter(am == 1) %>% pull(mpg), :
#> cannot compute exact p-value with ties
#> 
#>  Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  mtcars %>% filter(am == 1) %>% pull(mpg) and mtcars %>% filter(am == 0) %>% pull(mpg)
#> W = 205, p-value = 0.001871
#> alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

wilcox.test(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$am)
#> Warning in wilcox.test.default(x = c(21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, :
#> cannot compute exact p-value with ties
#> 
#>  Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  mtcars$mpg by mtcars$am
#> W = 42, p-value = 0.001871
#> alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

***N.B.***  If you want the exact same results you have to reverse your `filter` order since the `W` statistic is calculated for the order given although `p.value` remains the same.